# How do I ask Shake if a target is up to date, like `make -q`?

Tags: shake-build-system

With Make I can say `make -q [target]` and the exit code will indicate if the target is up to date. Does Shake have an equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shake doesn't currently have this feature, but it has been requested, and is on the todo list, see https://github.com/ndmitchell/shake/issues/289.